# Same variables and different values on instances

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice, variable

I have searched on google but I have not found a way to put different values in the variables of the same symbol placed more than once.

[image]

Each component "X11, X12..." etc, are the same, and in each have {RA} and {RB}, and I would like to simulate the entire circuit with different values of RA and RB in each.

Comment: So you want to set a global variable for RA/RB? When you created X# did you define RA/RB by editing their component attribute to "{X}",aka {RB} or {RA}?

Comment: you could try  `.param RA 1k` and see if that works.

Comment: My global variables are {RA} and {RB}, and when I use the same symbol to create an "array" I can´t change {RA} and {RB} individually for each symbol that I use. If I use .param RA 1k or .param list RA 1k 10k 100k, all resistances on all symbols will change to the same, and I need change {RA} and {RB} for each symbol.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an image of the "Component Attribute Editor" box that that pops up when you try to right-click on one of your instances?

Comment: I know there's at least one other answer that deals with this, but you need to add, for example, `{RA1}` to the first subcircuit, `{RA2}` to the 2nd, etc, and define, each, separately, as `.param RA1=1k RA2=2k ....`.

Answer (score 3):

These are the contents of the `opamp.sub` (installed by the LTSpice) file for an almost ideal opamp with two parameters:

```
.subckt opamp 1 2 3
G1 0 3 2 1 {Aol}
R3 3 0 1.
C3 3 0 {Aol/GBW/6.28318530717959}
.ends opamp
```

Whenever you use this model (".lib opamp.sub") you define these parameters at the *"SpiceLines"* of the parameter selection (right-click each symbol):

[image]

You can make them visible at the schematic by selecting the 'X's in the respective column.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this simple circuit. You would like to test the circuit by varying the values of R1 and checking the response at various points. [image: model]

Here's how you could do that:

1. Define R1's component parameter with a variable (CTRL-right-click), and for "Value" enter your variable name "{X}" . You must include the curly braces because this tells spice it is a parameter you'd like to edit in the future. The component's displayed value should show up as "R1  {X}" now.
2. Add a parameter command to define which values you'd like to assign to R1. You can define multiple values and use the .step command to "step" through each  `.step param X list 1k 2k`

Comment: Lets say that you want to make a symbol of the resistor and diode, then, in another circuit, you´ll use that symbol many times. Now, you want vary the variable {X}, but this have to be different for each symbol instanced. I mean, you have the same symbol and in each, I want to define different values for the resistance {X}, but I only have the variable {X}, and I would like have a different {X} for each symbol. I don´t want to create a symbol for each elemnt of an array that have the same component cell.